# Difference between ABC and US keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, language

I have found this: [Why does Mac OS include both ABC and US keyboard layouts when the two perform the same functions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418543/why-does-mac-os-include-both-abc-and-us-keyboard-layouts-when-the-two-perform-th), where the answer stated:

> ABC is just the same as US but you don't have an American flag. Some users outside the US may find that preferable.

---

However, this answer doesn't stand anymore, since the latest versions of macOS has used the <kbd>A</kbd> symbol for any English keyboard layouts if you only have one of them available. And they would only change to language/nation abbreviations if you have more than one English keyboard layouts(not flags anymore).

So my questions is, are there really no difference between ABC and US keyboard layouts now? Or are there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: Just check for yourself using Apple's keyboard viewer app.  Do you see any difference in the key mappings?

Comment: @TomGewecke I don't see any difference, but does that mean they are the same? There are also Australian English, Canadian English, and ABC - India that all seems to have the same glyphs.

Comment: ABC India does not have the same glyphs on option level.  It is a version of ABC Extended with the Rupee symbol added.  It's also possible that an app like Word that uses non-Apple spellcheck will switch spellcheck language according to the name of the keyboard, but I have not tested that.  MacOS sets spellcheck independently of keyboard.

Comment: Also Austrailian English has a slightly different layout when used on a Japanese JIS hardware keyboard.